# How to move some parts of a project into Git branches without losing their history?

Tags: git

I started my main project with CVS in 2006, I moved to Subversion in 2008 and I moved to Git in 2021 but at the very beginning, I was a newbie in version control and [my repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/tuer/git/ci/master/tree/) is messy, several distinct implementations of my game.

I would like to move them into separate branches but I don't want to lose the history between branches, i.e I would like to be able to find in the log that some files were initially in the "master" branch but were moved into the "pre-alpha" branch. How can I achieve that? Should I create a branch, switch to it, remove the files that have nothing to do in it, go back to the "master" branch and remove the files already in the new branch? Is it the proper way of using Git for this purpose?

P.S: I did this based on larsks' answer:

```
git subtree split -b prealpha --prefix trunk
git subtree split -b alpha --prefix alpha
git subtree split -b jme --prefix tuer
git push origin prealpha
git push origin alpha
git push origin jme
git subtree split -b prebeta --prefix pre_beta
git branch -m master oldmaster
git branch -m prebeta master
git push origin oldmaster
```

Only this last line doesn't work:

```
git push origin master
```

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error:
> impossible to push the references to
> 'https://gouessej@git.code.sf.net/p/tuer/git'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Subversion `-->` Git migration may have been sub-optimal; your `master` branch contains a bunch of top level directories that look like they probably correspond to Subversion branches. Your migration to Git should have converted these into Git branches.

I've taken a brief look at the project and I'm having a hard time discerning the relationship between the various branches. I would expect, e.g., that changes to `pre_beta` would at some point share a common history with the `alpha` code, but I'm not able to find obvious matches.

We can use `git subtree` to split those top-level directories into distinct branches. I would do something like:

```
git subtree split -b alpha --prefix alpha
git subtree split -b pre_beta --prefix pre_beta
git subtree split -b tuer --prefix tuer
git branch -m master old_master
git branch -m pre_beta master
```

This splits the history for each directory into a separate branch, and then turns the existing `pre_beta` branch into the `master` branch (because it seemed to have the most recent changes).

This gets you:

```
$ git branch
  alpha
* master
  old_master
  tuer
$ git checkout master
$ ls
branding.properties  lib          NOTICE.txt  src
build.xml            LICENSE.txt  README.txt  versioning.properties
$ git checkout alpha
$ ls
about.txt  changes_2.rtf  contents.txt  lib       md3         sound    tools
bean       com            drawer        main      readme.txt  target
build.xml  connection     gpl.txt       manifest  snd         texture
$ git checkout tuer
$ ls
about.txt  changes_2.rtf  contents.txt  jme   md2         snd      tools
bean       com            drawer        lib   obj         sound
build.xml  connection     gpl.txt       main  readme.txt  texture
$ git checkout old_master
$ ls
alpha  pre_beta  trunk  tuer
```

You can see the result at https://github.com/larsks/tuer-git.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer and the time spent to illustrate it by an example. You're very close to the result I expect. Actually, those implementations use 3 different engines (my fork of d3caster, JMonkeyEngine 2 and JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation) and share almost no source code. "trunk" is the ancestor of "alpha", both use my fork of d3caster. What's the interest of keeping old_master?

Comment: There's no particular reason to keep `old_master`.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try very soon. Using `git subtree` seems to be an excellent idea

Comment: I can't push the master branch but the rest worked as expected. Do you know why? I've just updated my question.

Comment: You can't push your `master` branch because the history no longer matches the existing `master` branch. You can force push it (`git push -f origin master`), which will overwrite the remote `master` with the contents of your local `master` branch. Note that hosting platforms have force push disabled by default, so you may need to tweak a configuration setting. I'm not familiar with Sourceforge's git hosting.

Comment: I prefer giving up, I don't succeed in making it work with Sourceforge, I don't want to use a platform owned by Microsoft and I'm not fully ready to host my source code on my server at home but your answer is clearly a path in the good direction.

Answer (score 0):

In short...yes.

You should make a new branch off of `master`, and then make whatever changes are necessary to make each branch (`master` and the new branch) right.

Note that it can be appropriate to make the branch, and then move a completely different copy of your source into place as your current working copy of that branch.  Git will normally do the right thing in terms of the addition and removal of files.  Git often won't do so good a job with files that have been renamed or moved.  In these cases, a file might be treated as new even though it was really an existing file that was moved or renamed.  To fix that, you need to make those changes via `git mv` on the original contents of the branch to make sure `git` gets them right.

Comment: Ok but I'm not sure that I can use git mv on directories.

Comment: @gouessej sure you can.